# Eclipse code completion automatic deactivation

Tags: java, eclipse, code-completion

Whenever I run Eclipse, it suddenly deactivates some completions tags (but not all) with no reason. This happens always during, when I write some code. At the start of Eclipse, everything is okay but after a while this problem occurs. Every time I solve this by resetting the preferences and restarting Eclipse. But it takes too much time and annoys me.
Is there a special Hot-Key to (de)activate some completions tags?

Comment: **completions tags** - you mean html tag completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet on a plugin malfunction.  Try to reinstall Eclipse from scratch without any custom plugins, and add only what you need, then add them one by one until you run into this problem.

Alternatively, open Eclipse->preferences->install/update->unintsall or update (link)->configuration->view error log and see if you get any exceptions on any plugins, if you identify something fishy, uninstall that plugin.

Comment: To confirm this, check the `.log` file in your local workspace. There are probably exception messages from the plugins.

Comment: I inspected the error log  and it seems, that there is alway an ArrayOutOfBoundsException. The whole log for this specific happening is about 150 rows long, so copy+paste makes no sense ;)
The packages are: 
org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di
org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget

Comment: 1. try to reinstall eclipse as in step (1), 2. try to clean your project, it's a long shot, but sometimes the project files are messed up and it affect eclipse.  oh and 3. make sure you don't have any weird characters in one of your files (or does it also happen when you start a new project?)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Eclipse Preferences named Type Filters (under Java | Appearance) seemed to cause that experience. We had excluded all common root package names (com.*, org.*, sun.*), but also java.* and javax.*. After deaktivating those entries in the "Filter list" Eclipse's Ctrl-Space again provides the missed proposals.